# Adding second file server for a web site

Tags: apache-2.2, nfs

I run a website that contains a lot of large files and even after buying the maximum amount of space my host provides on a single server (8x2TB drives) I am now running low on disk space.

I would like to add a second server purely for storing and serving files. My question is what is the best practice way for doing this? Mounting the new server using NFS is one way. Another way is to rewrite my application to utilize multiple servers but this is a LOT of work.

Is there an easy way to isolate the underlying storage from the web server so that to the web server it all appears as a single path, but is actually spread across multiple servers?

My OS is Linux CentOS, my server is Apache.

Note that the only issue I am facing is disk space, not bandwidth or cpu etc. I don't need to load balance the traffic, only add more space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that NFS is the way to go, but there are some other options, like FreeNAS (FreeBSD based), [AoE](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/553), which stands for ATA over Ethernet, and SAMBA but I would not recommend it unless you're looking also for windows interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much cost which you have.But in this case, we can use NAS or for the better with SAN to replacing space on the servers. 
Advantages with Storage Area

- With NAS/SAN you still using NFS or some popular protocol with high speed to share files between many servers. Not need to change many configuration on the servers.
- With NAS/SAN you can scale your systems any time, you never meet the issues about diskspace, cause by you can order many disk and hot plug to this immediately. 
  Amazing that when all your servers not need to configure for storing data in local, and when 1 or 2 nodes down you still running your services normally. IT 's so good

Disadvantages with SAN

- COST. But if you must order another server with many disks what can be better ?

Answer (score 0):

When you start needing to deal with the amount of data storage you currently have, you really only have two options as far as I see it:

1) Use an object store like Amazon S3 or Rackspace Cloud Files for your data. This will give you a nearly limitless storage capacity, and will relieve your server from needing to serve those files.

2) Start managing your own equipment. Sure, you could possibly get some sort of clustered filesystem up and running on a managed dedicated server, but you're going to be fighting the system in a lot of ways. In order to ensure reliable data storage, you're going to need several servers, and costs will go up pretty quickly.

Comment: This is a sensible answer but unfortunately option 1 is too expensive and option 2 is too much work for me at the moment. I forgot to mention that it took about 2 years to get to the current amount of data so by adding a second server I am buying another 2 years of time and hopefully by then I'll be able to justify a better solution. I'm too new to the site to be allowed to vote up answers :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting more external diskspace. Any serious hosting provider should be able to provide you with a SAN system, that can expand almost unlimited. But I'd advice against using NFS. In my experience apache and NFS don't always work seamlessly together. You are better to use a proper SAN protocol like iSCSI. You want a dedicated disk device for your server, not a disk share.

Comment: That would be nice but my host (reliable servers) does not offer it and I am not really aware that many hosting companies do.

Answer (score 0):

What you usually want is to scale the throughout with the number of servers. It's hard to saw without knowing the details of our application, but I will suggest to use the distributes nature of your set up. With HTTP you have a good opportunity to redirect requests to different servers depending on path.

Well, NFS will work as well, but at some point your web werver will be the bottle neck

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers about advantages of different disk solutions, but there's another option, too. You could simply have more than one web server, and serve different parts of the site from different servers.

One possibility is to split your site up based on the type of resource. E.g: Much of the content is images, so you set up a separate webserver with the hostname `images.yourdomain.com`. Then you change all the links to images in your application to no longer point to e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/images/image1.jpg` and instead point to `http://images.yourdomain.com/image1.jpg`.

You could also do this by using mod_rewrite, so that when a browser requests a resource from `/images /whatever.jpg` it will be rewriten to `http://images.yourdomain.com/whatever.jpg`.

A third option is to use mod_proxy, to forward certain requests to a second server without rewriting it. The downside to this is that all requests for images will now be passed through both servers, affecting CPU, memory and network. Even if they're not a problem now, they may be in the future.

I don't know if any of this is useful to you; it would depend on how your application is written.

Comment: Thanks, that was one option I considered but the way my app is written makes it just too much work.